# WP Query Order by Meta Key ASC not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to order a `WP_Query` acending by the `_sale_price` meta field.  I have tried using both `order_by` `meta_value` and `meta_value_num` but they both return the posts in the wrong order (the first 20 posts are in order by after that there are lower value products appearing after higher value products).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',

    'meta_key' =>  '_sale_price',

    'posts_per_page'          => -1,

    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_sale_price',
            'value'         => 0,
            'compare'       => '>',
            'type'          => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);

$sale_books = new WP_Query($args);
```

[image]

I also have tried a custom query and it still is wrong:

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND  $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value > 0
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'product'

ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC";
```

and I have tried casting the value `ORDER BY  CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) ASC` still does not work.

They are simple products
[image]

Here is what happens when I echo the row index number and `get_post_meta($row->ID,'_sale_price',true)` .
It ascends fine up until row 210 then products with lower prices start appearing:[image]

I have solved it with `usort` but I would still be insterested in why it isn't working:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{

    $testa = floatval(get_post_meta($a->ID, '_sale_price', true));
    $testb = floatval(get_post_meta($b->ID, '_sale_price', true));



    return  $testa <=> $testb;
}



usort($pageposts, "cmp");
```

Comment: OK, but why is the Query not returning the results in the correct order, I've checked the values and they are all numbers.

Comment: They are simple products. and as I said in quest I have tried `meta_value_num`.

Comment: Added output from looping through the query results.